# Laravel & React, dynamically render on the fly

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I recently started on React and I'm using it in combination with Laravel as I would like to replace my jquery by react on a step by step migration.

In my tests, the render instructions are always packaged in the component .js file like this :

`ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById('tutorial'));`

and the div `<div id="tutorial"></div>` is placed in a view.

My problem is that the view is dynamically generated by my php code and sometimes I need to render several component in one page so this approach is not working. Hence I would like to trigger the rendering from the view so something like :

`<div id="tutorial" intruction_to_render_calculator_component_in_this_div></div>`

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

been all over it recently in trying to find a solution... So here is the one I found :

In my component I put a loop to screen all elements asking to be mount based on an rComponent attribute :

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("[rComponent='Calculator']");
if (divs.length > 0) {
  //document.querySelector("[rComponent='calculator']");
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, divs[i]);
  }

  //ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById('tutorial2'));
}
```

In my view I just need to put a rComponent in my div :

```
<div id="tutorial" rComponent="Calculator"></div>
<div id="tutorial2" rComponent="Calculator"></div>
```

pretty happy with this way of working though I think it might slow the scripts high time